# Apache Flink best practices - when to run separate tasks

Tags: apache-flink

Regarding best practices and efficiency within Flink, what are the recommendations of when to split analytics into multiple tasks

For example, given a single topic in Kafka as the source of the data. If there were many simple operations that were to be carried out over the stream, such as: if some value is greater than x, or if x & y etc. What would be the point at which you would stop spending more rules into the same task and start to run them in parallel?

Is there any official recommendation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a general recommendation. Performance-wise, it makes sense to put as much as possible into one job.

However, it's much more important to think about maintenance. I'd put everything in one job that is closely related, such that new features or bug fixes will likely only affect one job while at the same time, you also don't want to stop all analytics when upgrading one particular query.

Another dimension to think about is state size. It's related to restarts and update frequency (point above). If the state size becomes too big, restarting this one monster job takes a long time, which would be inefficient if you only touched a small fraction of the code.

Finally, it also depends on the relevance. If some part of your job is super important as it reflects the one KPI that drives your business, then you probably don't want to mix that with some fragile, unimportant part.